# Heroku: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_hub.tf_v1' has no attribute 'estimator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

I test my application locally and it works.
Than deploying to Heroku via 
git push heroku master

I get following error from log file:

2019-11-14T15:59:58.097757+00:00 app[web.1]:**import tensorflow_hub as hub**
2019-11-14T15:36:33.331739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/**init**.py", line 29, in 
2019-11-14T15:36:33.331740+00:00 app[web.1]: from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
2019-11-14T15:36:33.331741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py", line 63, in 
2019-11-14T15:36:33.331742+00:00 app[web.1]: class LatestModuleExporter(tf_v1.estimator.Exporter):
2019-11-14T15:36:33.331746+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_hub.tf_v1' has no attribute 'estimator'
2019-11-14T15:36:33.333083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-14 15:36:33 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

#### requirements.txt:

absl-py==0.8.1

amqp==2.5.2

astor==0.8.0

billiard==3.6.1.0

cachetools==3.1.1

celery==4.3.0

certifi==2019.9.11

chardet==3.0.4

Click==7.0

Flask==1.1.1

gast==0.2.2

google-auth==1.7.1

google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1

google-pasta==0.1.8

grpcio==1.25.0

gunicorn==20.0.0

h5py==2.10.0

idna==2.8

importlib-metadata==0.23

itsdangerous==1.1.0

Jinja2==2.10.3

joblib==0.14.0

Keras-Applications==1.0.8

Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0

kombu==4.6.6

Markdown==3.1.1

MarkupSafe==1.1.1

more-itertools==7.2.0

numpy==1.17.4

oauthlib==3.1.0

opt-einsum==3.1.0

protobuf==3.10.0

pyasn1==0.4.7

pyasn1-modules==0.2.7

pytz==2019.3

PyYAML==5.1.2

redis==3.3.11

requests==2.22.0

requests-oauthlib==1.3.0

rsa==4.0

scikit-learn==0.21.3

scipy==1.3.2

six==1.13.0

sklearn==0.0

tensorboard==2.0.1

tensorflow==2.0.0a0

tensorflow-estimator==2.0.1

tensorflow-hub==0.7.0

termcolor==1.1.0

urllib3==1.25.7

vine==1.3.0

Werkzeug==0.16.0

wrapt==1.11.2

zipp==0.6.0

#### runtime.txt:

python-3.7.2

Any idea? Thanks...

Comment: at https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/tensorflow_hub/tf_v1.py I found this comment: "TensorFlow Hub Authors Internal change: tf_v1.estimator should really be v1, not v2. " ..may be this could be useful, but I don't understand how fix the problem on Heroku.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I've run into the same problem.  It works fine locally, but when I push to Heroku I see `AttributeError ... module 'wakemeup.models' has no attribute 'environment'`  I'm trying to import `wakemeup.models.environment`